# Is NASM inconsistent or am I just missing an obvious fact with CMP of immediate?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

The "warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds" is the ***bane of my existence*** at the moment as it appears to be inconsistent or I am just not seeing an obvious fact.

I have the following structure declared:

```
struc   FRTType        
        .class    resq  1   ; Class
        .type     resq  1   ; Type
endstruc
```

I have the following assigns:

```
%assign TYPE_SCALAR     0xfffffffffffffff1
%assign INTEGER         0xffffffff1000a8a9
```

And in a function I have:

```
cmp     qword [rdi+FRTType.class], TYPE_SCALAR  ; This works fine
jne     .exception
cmp     qword [rdi+FRTType.type], INTEGER       ; THIS PRODUCES WARNING
```

I know I can `mov rax, INTEGER` and then do the compare but that seems unneeded given the first compare has no problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no `CMP r/m64,imm64`.
There's `CMP r/m64,imm32`, where `imm32` is sign-extended to 64 bits. Which works fine for `0xfffffffffffffff1`, because `0xfffffff1` sign-extended to 64 bits is `0xfffffffffffffff1`. But `0x1000a8a9` sign-extended to 64 bits is `0x000000001000a8a9`, which differs from the value you wanted to compare against.

You could overcome this e.g. by loading the immediate into a register first:

```
mov rax, INTEGER
cmp     qword [rdi+FRTType.type], rax
```

Comment: Ipso facto, I missed an obvious fact. Staring at the Intel instruction guide it is clear that "sometimes you have to step away from the vehicle". Thank you Michael!